# What commands/environments are supported by jLatexMath?

Tags: rendering, java

Is there documentation on which commands are available?
For example right now I cant even `\\` to get linebreaks, however `\textcolor{red}{\mathfrak{A}rea}A=\pi r^2` works perfectly...

Comment: As far as I can tell this package does not use LaTeX to render, but rather it emulates a a subset of LaTeX commands. Therefore I do not think that it's a good fit for TeX.sx.

Comment: At [the homepage of jLaTeXMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/) there is an uncomplete list.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I was inspecting the homepage inside out, but somehow refused to interpret the welcoming page...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You could add this as an answer. As I see close votes: I think, the question is ontopic here, as JLaTeXMath works with LaTeX syntax, even if it's not really LaTeX or TeX.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Done.

Answer (score 6):

The [homepage of jLaTeXMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/) has an uncomplete list of available commands:

> The most of LaTeX commands are available and:
>
> 1. macros from `amsmath` and symbols from `amssymb` and `stmaryrd`;
> 2. `\includegraphics` (without options);
> 3. the TeX macro `\over`;
> 4. accents from `amsxtra` package;
> 5. the macros `\definecolor`, `\textcolor`, `\colorbox` and `\fcolorbox` from the package `color`;
> 6. the macros `\rotatebox`, `\reflectbox` and `\scalebox` from the package `graphicx`;
> 7. the most of latin unicode characters are available and cyrillic or
>      greek characters are detected for the loading of the different
>      fonts;
> 8. the commands `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment`;
> 9. the environments `array`, `matrix`, `pmatrix`,..., `eqnarray`, `cases`;
> 10. the vertical and horizontal lines are handled in `array` environment;
> 11. the commands to change the size of the font are available : `\tiny`,
>       `\small`,...,`\LARGE`, `\huge`, `\Huge`,
> 12. the fonts are embedded in the jar file to be used by fop 0.95 to generate PDF, PS or EPS (SVG export with shaped fonts works fine too).
>       Since the version 0.9.5, the fop
>       plugin is fully compatible with fop 1.0 and xmlgraphics 1.4;
> 13. and probably other things I forgot...

Answer (score 0):

JLaTeXMath is the library used by GeoGebra to display math expressions written in LaTeX.
You can see lists of the GeoGebra LaTeX commands in:

- https://help.geogebra.org/topic/geogebra-latex-tips-font-size-color-box-and-math-
- https://help.geogebra.org/topic/latex-environments-list-that-is-working-in-geogebra

And in the source code of JLaTeXMath:

- https://github.com/geogebra/geogebra/blob/master/retex/renderer-base/src/main/java/com/himamis/retex/renderer/share/Commands.java